# How can I copy the whole number under the cursor?

Tags: cut-copy-paste

Lets say I have a list like this:

```
marcus1235lt
jonas3456lt
       ^Cursor is here
thomas345pt
```

how can I yank the number under the cursor, in this case 3456, without getting any characters?

Comment: From the beginning of the number `y/\D/e-<enter>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/\d\+
```

searches for one or more digits, as many as possible.

```
N
```

repeats the search in the opposite direction because `/` moved the cursor to the next match.

```
ygn
```

yanks the current match of the previous search. See `:help gn`.

Combined, you get a relatively simple mapping that yanks the number under the cursor:

```
nnoremap <key> /\d\+<CR>Nygn
```

---

But text objects are one of my favorite Vim feature. Here is a crude alternative to the plugins mentioned in the other answer, if you feel like travelling light:

```
function! VisualNumber()
    call search('\d\([^0-9\.]\|$\)', 'cW')
    normal v
    call search('\(^\|[^0-9\.]\d\)', 'becW')
endfunction
xnoremap in :<C-u>call VisualNumber()<CR>
onoremap in :<C-u>normal vin<CR>
```

Comment: You can use `?` instead of `/` followed by a `N`. Also I'd cancel the search highlight so I think we can use `:nnoremap <silent> yin ?\d\+<CR>ygn:nohls<CR>`

Comment: No. `?` only works the way you want when the cursor is *in* a number. When it is on the first digit, the cursor jumps to the previous number and you need `N` to come back. Meaning that `?` can have different outcomes, which have to be dealt with in the mapping. On the other hand, `/` always has the same outcome, no matter where the cursor is in the number, so it always requires a `N`, which makes things much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

If you consider installing plug-ins for this purpose, look into:

- https://github.com/MisanthropicBit/vim-numbers

Or:

- https://github.com/tkhren/vim-textobj-numeral

Both of them add a `in` text object for numerical strings, so you can use `yin` to yank the number under the cursor with any of these two plug-ins installed.